# Is it possible to add 10 subdomains in a separate cPanel account from the main domain?

Tags: domains, cpanel, whm, add-on-domain

I would like to know is it possible to have one domain in a separate cPanel account and all the subdomains in another separate account.

Main domain: One cpanel account.

10 subdomains: One cpanel account.

Answer (score 3):

I would think this is possible, but perhaps not in the way you'd expect.

`example.com` (the domain apex) would be the primary domain on Account#1

`subdomain1.example.com` would be the primary domain on Account#2 and `subdomain2.example.com` to `subdomain10.example.com` would be configured as Addon domains. (Or, perhaps use a "special" subdomain as the primary domain and `subdomain1` to `subdomain10` all as Addon domains - for consistency.)

Comment: It also depends on limits on add on domains imposed by the hosting company.   cPanel lets the hosting company set limits on the number of add on domains.   I think most hosting companies allow at least 10, but they need to check with their particular hosting company.